# How to replace infected `/lib/libsh.so` and `/etc/sh.conf` files?

Tags: linux, rootkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server’s been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

Which package does the file /lib/libsh.so belong to?

I need to replace it since it was infected. Same for /etc/sh.conf.

For now I have moved it to /temp/libsh.so.infected. Can I just delete it?

**Edit 1:**

I just found out that libsh.so isn't a file but a directory with following files:
bash
shdcf
shhk
shhk.pub
shrs

Comment: Once a server's been compromised, you don't play around with the files here and there. You wipe it and re-install and restore your data files from backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't files I've ever heard of. Googling for libsh.so brings up results related to the SHV4/5 rootkit. Here's a [blog post detailing symptoms and removal](http://www.huweb.hu/maques/mblog/?p=153)

Comment: Yes, the files belong to rootkit, REMOVED immediately!

Answer (score 0):

What distribution do you have ? Matching file to package totally depends on package manager ->  {and thus to distribution}.

In any case, for rpms (Fedora, Redhat, Centos ...) you can do it with `rpm -qf /lib/libsh.so`